# Differential Equations Existence and Uniqueness Textbook Question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to stay ahead of my class by doing some of the later homework questions. One thing I don't fully understand is the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem, and the question is the following:

> Determine whether a solution exists, and if its unique.
>   
>   $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x-y}$, $y(2)=2$
>   
>  
>   My solution: 
>   The function is continuous for all $x-y \geq 0$, and since $2 \geq 2$, there exists a solution. For $f_y = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-y}}$, the function is continuous for all $x>y$ but 2 isn't greater or equal to 2, so the solution isn't unique.

In the textbook it says that neither a solution exists or is unique, and I'm just a bit confused as to why it doesn't exits. Maybe I could gain some intuition, and a new way of thinking.

Thanks.

Comment: Whether a solution exists depends on the interval considered.  Does it specify an interval for which existence should be considered?  It is clear that there is no solution if the interval is the real line, but for certain subsets it will exist.

Comment: I'm given the initial point. Isn't that enough? The question doesn't specify how large the interval is. But I'm assuming it's the real numbers. Can you explain why no solutions exist? And maybe show some work?

Comment: The problem occurs when x is less than y, so there is no.solution for any $x<2$.  So there is no neighborhood of $x=2$ where a solution exists.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit confused

Comment: Although the answer given already is correct, one annoying thing about elementary ODE is that the existence/uniqueness theorem they use is not very general. So sometimes it doesn't apply but a unique solution exists anyway, for example $y'=|y|,y (0)=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theorem says that a unique solution will exist if $f$ (and $\partial f /\partial x$) is continuous in an *open* rectangle containing the initial point.  Every open rectangle containing $(2,2)$ also contains some points with $x<y$.  So the hypotheses of the theorem are not met.  (The key word here is "open".)

Comment: You meant $\partial f/\partial y $, though it did not matter.